# Socket.IO 0.9.0 disconnects after 25 seconds on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO 0.9.0 to avoid the disconnection bug discussed here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/777

Everything works fine on my local machine, but on Heroku the client continues to disconnect every 25 seconds. Why would this be?

Here is my io configuration:

```
  io.configure ->
    # For heroku
    # https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku
    io.set "transports", ["xhr-polling"]
    io.set "polling duration", 10
    # Use Redis to store client logic
    # io.set "store", redisStoreSocketIO
    # Minify the client libraries
    io.enable 'browser client minification'
    # Tag for caching or something
    io.enable 'browser client etag'
    # GZIP client libraries
    io.enable 'browser client gzip'
    # Make it so sockets doesn't write to log every 3 seconds
    io.set 'log level', 1
    return
```

I checked my git commit logs and confirmed that Heroku is using the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by switching to NodeJitsu. :P
I'd be interested in hearing if anyone else encountered this though.